# How come this css transform animation isn't working?

Tags: css, google-chrome, animation

I was trying to follow along with this animation tutorial, and it would work in DreamWeaver (tho the live preview is not as "live" as I expected, as in it doesn't update immediately or even on save which is kind of annoying ... Any hints on how to make it work?) but not when I opened it in Chrome or IE. I was looking into it and everyone kept saying to add -webkit- and set display to inline-block since for some reason transform doesn't work otherwise, so I did, but it's still not working :<

```
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: coral;
  display: inline-block;
  animation: square-to-circle 2s 12s infinite alternate;
}

@-webkit-keyframes square-to-circle {
  0% {
      border-radius: 0 0 0 0;
      background: coral;
      transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
  25% {
      border-radius: 100% 0 0 0;
      background: darksalmon;
      transform: rotate(45deg);
    }
  50% {
      border-radius: 100% 100% 0 0;
      background: indianred;
      transform: rotate(90deg);
    }
  75% {
      border-radius: 100% 100% 100% 0;
      background: lightcoral;
      transform: rotate(135deg);
    }
  100% {
      border-radius: 100%;
      background: darksalmon;
      transform: rotate(180deg);
    }
}
```

Comment: 12 s delay is not working for you?

Comment: ok, i'm an idiot :I ... had it backwards %\ ... thank you!

Comment: Np, happens. :)